# Scheduling an email in salesforce

Tags: apex, email

Can we schedule an email in salesforce via Apex?

Can we make recurring email task in salesforce?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pramod have you actually tried looking this up yourself yet ? Please do some effort of your own, or share with us what you've already tried to debug or answer a question you're asking. Let's try to keep in mind that these questions stick around on the internet for a long while, and we should strive to ask questions that aren't already answered in many other online resources, and collect good answers so that they can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes

Next question................

Comment: Thank your for reply. How can we do that?